# I need help on how to make a loop inside a case that it is inside a do-while loop

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

I'm trying to make a while (true) loop inside of a case with a do-while loop but when I put the while (true) in the case the menu doesn't loop back to the console and I need to close the debugger and run it again can someone help me I'm new to c++.

Here is my code:

```
do
{
    std::cout << "[0] Quit\n"; // This is Option 0 of the Menu
    std::cout << "[1] Infinite Health\n"; // This is Option 1 of the Menu
    std::cout << "[2] Infinite Ammo\n"; // This is Option 2 of the Menu
    std::cout << "[3] Infinite Rounds\n"; // This is Option 3 of the Menu
    std::cin >> choice;


    switch (choice) // This is to detect the Choice the User selected
    {
    case 0:
        std::cout << "Why did you even open me to not use me :(\n";
        return 0;

    case 1:
        std::cout << "You Have Activated Infinite Health!\n";
        
        while (true)
        {
            int health = 1000;
            WriteProcessMemory(phandle, (LPVOID*)(healthPtrAddr), &health, 4, 0);
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        std::cout << "You Have Activated Infinite Ammo On Primary Weapon!\n";

        while (true)
        {
            int ammo = 500;
            WriteProcessMemory(phandle, (LPVOID*)(ammoPtrAddr), &ammo, 4, 0);
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        std::cout << "You Have Activated Infinite Rounds On Primary Weapon!";

        while (true)
        {
            int rounds = 200;
            WriteProcessMemory(phandle, (LPVOID*)(roundsPtrAddr), &rounds, 4, 0);
        }
        break;
    }
} 
while (choice !=0);
```

Comment: `while (true)` never completes, and you're not doing anything to break out of it.    Why are you trying to use it here?

Comment: how do I complete the while (true)?
I'm using it to write memory, I can remove the break but it doesn't do anything

Comment: what is the point of the `while(true)`?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to make a loop in which for example the ammo is always at 100 but when I click the option it says infinite ammo activated but it doesn't go back to the menu

Comment: I think most of this should be explained by a C++ tutorial. In any case, it would help if you extracted a [mcve] first and include that and the output in your question, along with exact info how you interact with the program. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it doesn't return, because it is blocking the program.

To solve your problem you could put the loop inside of another thread.

if you include the thread library using:

```cpp
#include <thread>
```

You'd then have to define the function that should run:

```cpp
void keepHealth() {
    while (true)
    {
        int health = 1000;
        WriteProcessMemory(phandle, (LPVOID*)(healthPtrAddr), &health, 4, 0);
    }
}
```

You can now execute this function in another thread with:

```cpp
std::thread task1(keepHealth);
```

If you want to pass arguments like your handles, you'd have to write them in the function header:

```cpp
void keepHealth(void* pHandle, void* healthPtrAddress) {
    while (true)
    {
        int health = 1000;
        WriteProcessMemory(phandle, (LPVOID*)(healthPtrAddr), &health, 4, 0);
    }
}
```

and pass them like this:

```cpp
std::thread task1(keepHealth, pHandle, healthPtrAddress);
```

Comment: I do not understand what you said, as said I'm new to c++ sorry : )

Comment: Ok, so the process that is running will be blocked by a while-true loop. That is because your cpu is trapped inside it and cannot execute further instructions since it runs them one at a time. But if tell the cpu to use a different core, it will be able to run these instructions simultaneously. I oversimplified this heavily, I recommend you to read more into this topic

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: did you get it to work?

Comment: yes i did! thank you